# Nativescript: Validation doesn't work [disabled]="!RegisterForm.valid"

Tags: forms, validation, nativescript

I try to use this html code in Nativescript for Register user. I want to disable button register. If I put input I want to enable this button.

In this code I put: `[ngClass]="{invalid: invalidCredentials}"` and in button [disabled]="!RegisterForm.valid"

```
<GridLayout backgroundColor="#f1f1f1">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center" [formGroup]="RegisterForm" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
            padding="15">
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField formControlName="username" hint="Username" [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidCredentials}">
                </TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField formControlName="password" hint="Password " secure="true" [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidCredentials}">
                </TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary w-full" text="Register" [disabled]="!RegisterForm.valid" (tap)="register()"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

In ts component I have this code:

```
loading: boolean = false;
invalidCredentials: boolean = false;

register() {
    this.loading = true;
    let newRegister = this.RegisterForm.value
    let user = new User(newRegister);
    this.ws.registergetdata(user).subscribe(
        result => {
              ....
            } else {
                this.loading = false;
                this.invalidCredentials = true;          
           }
        });
     }
```

Works good but validation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` is not a known property, it supposed to be [isEnabled](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_button_.button#isenabled).

Comment: Okay thank you! How to write this `[disabled]=“!RegisterForm.valid”` ??

Comment: As simple as `[isEnabled]="RegisterForm.valid"`